# 'for' loop fail in multidimentional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Question is: Checking two matrices, if one is a sub matrix of another.

The problem I am facing here is a `for` loop as commented as "//problem" in the code. When for the first time the program runs, the mentioned `for` loop does not work as it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

int
main ()
{

  char matrix1[N][N], matrix2[N][N];
  int i, j, row1, col1, row2, col2, k, l, m, n, check = 0;

  //First Matrix
  printf ("Enter the data\n");
  printf ("Enter the size of rows\n");
  scanf ("%d", &row1);   
  printf ("Enter the size of columns\n");
  scanf ("%d", &col1);   
  printf ("Now enter the values please\n");

  //Putting Values In First Matrix
  for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < col1; j++)
        {
          printf ("Please enter the %dth row and %dth column\n", i + 1,
                  j + 1);
          scanf ("%s", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    }

  //Second Matrix
  printf ("Enter the data\n");
  printf ("Enter the size of rows\n");
  scanf ("%d", &row2);   
  printf ("Enter the size of columns\n");
  scanf ("%d", &col2);   
  printf ("Now enter the values please\n");

  //Putting Values In Second Matrix
  for (i = 0; i < row2; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        {
          printf ("Please enter the %dth row and %dth column\n", i + 1,
                  j + 1);
          scanf ("%s", &matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    }

  //Checking Both Matrices
  for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < col1; j++)
        {
          if (matrix1[i][j] == matrix2[0][0])
            {
              k = i;
              l = j;
              for (m = 0; m < row2; m++)
                {
                  for (n = 0; n < col2; n++)
                    {           //problem
                      if (matrix1[k][l] == matrix2[m][n])
                        {
                          check++;
                          printf ("Checked\n");
                        }
                      l++;
                    }
                  l = j; 
                  k++;   
                }
            }
        }
      printf ("hello\n");
    }
  if (check == row2 * col2)
    {
      printf ("It exists\n");
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("It doesn't exist\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 Checked
 hello
 Checked
 Checked
 Checked
 Checked
 hello
 hello
 It doesn't exist
```

Comment: try to be more precise, how is your matrix defined? is it a int [][] or a float [][]? This is important because float comparison in C is not always working.

Comment: its int...let me put the whole code

Comment: So check is 5, but what are the values of row2 and col2?

Comment: You should use prefix incrementation (`++i`) when possible. Also, wrapping it all up in function will certainly help.

Comment: @tanzeeb it should be 4,its 2x2 matrix,as u can see for the first time its doesnt loop back..@Bartek dont u think it will be same problem there ..

Comment: @riz Do you want to store a single character inside each cell of your matrix ? You have made room for just 1 char in each cell. You're using `scanf ("%s", &matrix1[i][j])` which tries to store a string (which would normally be many chars), but there's only room for 1 char.

Comment: @nos Yes,I store just one char,but when I use a scanf ("%c",&matrix[i][j]) I experience strange output,I cant fill the rows!!

Comment: @riz Well, when you type one character to be placed in one cell, you probably hit the enter key afterwards. You'll need some code to read that newline too, otherwise the next scanf("%c" will read it into the next cell.

Comment: @nos lol,yes you are right.The issue reslolved.Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset `check` to zero before starting to find sub-matrix. 
Also to break once you found it (or have flag to indicate if its found).

As from your output, (assuming you are trying to find 2x2 matrix) it found it `Checked` printed  times continuously, but its value would be 5 counting for 1st print as well, which makes your program to print `"It does not exist"`.

Like:

```
int is_found = 0;
... //some code
//Checking Both Matrices
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < col1; j++)
    {
      check = 0;   //reset check
      if (matrix1[i][j] == matrix2[0][0])
        {
      ... //your code to check matrix.
      ...
      }//if end
      if(check == row2*col2) 
      {
          is_found = 1;
      }
      ...
   } //for j end
   if(is_found)
      break;
   ...

 ...
 if(is_found)
    printf("It exists\n");
```

Comment: @riz Need to reset before each test, otherwise it will keep incrementing for partial matches as well.